# What to put in a MySQL auto-increment primary key field when inserting a row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, binding

I'm new to PHP and I'm having a little trouble setting up my code to auto increment IDs for SQL. I'm aware that the method that I am attempting isn't a very good approach and know about the risks of race conditions etc. This will be temporary until I sort the rest of my code out properly.

Could somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Or help me to get valid code?

My Class:

```
<?php

    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'testuser';

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die('Unable to connect');

    $data = json_decode(trim(key($_POST), '[]'), true);

    $email = $data['email'];
    $name = $data['name'];
    $shortDes = $data['shortDes'];
    $longDes = $data['longDes'];
    $max = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT MAX(society_id) FROM society');
    $society_id = $max + 1;

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO society(society_id, name, email, short_des, long_des) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'issss', $societyId, $name, $email, $shortDes, $longDes);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Focusing on the following snippet:

```
$max = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT MAX(society_id) FROM society');
        $society_id = $max + 1;

        $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO society(society_id, name, email, short_des, long_des) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'issss', $societyId, $name, $email, $shortDes, $longDes);
```

Comment: You are not executing your `$max` query nor fetching any result. Also you should use an alias for `MAX()` function

Comment: Why not let MySQL handle the auto incrementing for you? Since it's designed to do that.

Comment: Well I set my primary keys to auto increment, pretty sure I did it correctly, but it doesn't work. I'll take a deeper look into that right now

Comment: Damn it, so if I just skip the entry of the auto incremented id it generates it for me?

Comment: Yes, in MySQL there's no need to supply a value for auto-increment fields.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to remove the value for the auto incremented field altogether.